# I'm trying to read data from an hash table into a linked list

Tags: pointers, data-structures, nodes, hashtable

Im trying to read data from an global hashtable into a linked list. I cant seem to see where I went wrong. Each time I run the program, I get a runtime error.

```
node *locallinkedlist = NULL;
   
//Reading Data From the global hashtable into a local linked list to find data using binary search
    for(int p = 0; p < 25; p++)
    {
        for(node *c = hashtable[p]; c != NULL; c = c->next)
        {
            if(locallinkedlist == NULL)
            {
                locallinkedlist = c;
            }
            else
            {
                c = locallinkedlist;
                locallinkedlist = c;
            }
            
        }
    }

    for(node *h = locallinkedlist; h != NULL; h=h->next)
    {
        printf("%s",h->employeefirstname);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
I need to create a node pointer using malloc inside the inner for loop, for each employee and store each of those employee name inside the node pointer and then put it into the list. Heres my revides code!!:

```
node *head = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for(node *j = hashtable[i]; j != NULL; j = j->next)
        {
            node *m = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if(m == NULL)//Checking for a valid memory address
            {
                return 1;
            }
            strcpy(m->employeefirstname,j->employeefirstname);
            m->next = NULL;
            if(head == NULL)
            {
                head = m;
            }
            else
            {
                m->next = head;
                head = m;
            }
        }
    }
    for(node *c = head; c != NULL; c = c->next)
    {
        printf("%s\n",c->employeefirstname);
    }
```